# Momentum Space Propagator from Path Integral Formulation of “Polyakov-style” action for a massive relativistic point particle

Tags: string-theory, path-integral, greens-functions, propagator

I have the derived the following expression for the propagator of a “Polyakov-style” action for a massive relativistic point particle:
\begin{equation*}
    G(X_2 - X_1) = \mathcal{N}'\int_{0}^{\infty}dl\int DX\exp\left(\frac{i}{2}\int_{0}^{l}d\tau' \left(\dot{X}^{2}-m^{2}\right)\right).
\end{equation*}
I think I was able to evaluate the functional integral by the normal trick of discretising into $N$ steps and then taking the limit as $N\rightarrow\infty$ keeping $N\Delta\tau' = const$ and arrived at the following expression:
\begin{gather*}
    \int DX\:\exp\left(\frac{i}{2}\int_{0}^{l}d\tau' \left(\dot{X}^{2}-m^{2}\right)\right) = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left(\prod_{j=1}^{N-1}\int dX_{j}\right)\exp{\left(\frac{i}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(\frac{({X}_{i}-{X}_{i-1})^{2}}{(\Delta\tau)^{2}}-m^{2}\right)\Delta\tau\right)}
    \\ = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2\pi l}}\exp{\left(\frac{i}{2}\frac{(X_{2}-X_{1})^{2}}{l}\right)}\exp{\left(-\frac{i}{2}m^{2}l\right)}.
\end{gather*}
So I have that
\begin{equation*}
     G(X_2 - X_1) = \int_{0}^{\infty}dl \sqrt{\frac{1}{2\pi l}}\exp{\left(\frac{i}{2}\frac{(X_{2}-X_{1})^{2}}{l}\right)}\exp{\left(-\frac{i}{2}m^{2}l\right)}.
\end{equation*}
I would like to show that in momentum space this gives
\begin{equation*}
    \tilde{G}(p)=\frac{1}{p^{2}+m^{2}}
\end{equation*}
but am unable to see how to proceed.

Note: This is not a homework assignment.

Comment: See [Lectures on the Worldline Formalism](https://indico.cern.ch/event/206621/attachments/317309/442801/lectures_morelia_CS.pdf), Schubert, eq (1.15).

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Hi Sidhaarth Kumar. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.